# Swift mail issue receipt Error: no valid recipients

Tags: php, laravel

im have issue with a mail config here is my error

> Swift_TransportException {#1847 ▼
> #message: """
> Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
> "
> """
> #code: 554
> #file: "/srv/disk2/2682915/www/prime.onehost.shop/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php"
> #line: 459
> trace: {▶}

Swift_TransportException code:

```
if (!$valid) {
    $this->throwException(new Swift_TransportException('Expected response code '.implode('/', $wanted).' but got code "'.$code.'", with message "'.$response.'"', $code));
}
}
```

Here is my mail.php code

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mboxhosting.com'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'contact@onehost.shop'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'PRIMEPOSTA'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('egzon@thetekhne.com'),

'password' => env('######'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

'stream' => [
   'ssl' => [
       'allow_self_signed' => true,
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false,
   ],
],

];
```

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=mboxhosting.com 
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=egzon@thetekhne.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=####
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls 
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contact@onehost.shop
MAIL_FROM_NAME=PRIMEPOSTA
```

Comment: `Error: no valid recipients` Sounds like you forgot the To Address

Comment: How can i solve it

Comment: Hello can u please help me sir

Comment: Perhaps setting the `To:` address is similar to adding the `From:` address...